# How to implement cert pinning with public keys in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, ssl-certificate, okhttp, public-key-pinning, trustkit

Is there an equivalent library like [TrustKit](https://github.com/datatheorem/TrustKit) that handles cert pinning with public keys hashes for Node? Or an http client that incorporates the pinning like [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/CertificatePinner.html) does for Android?